# Loading Assembly at runtime so that I can access all of it's types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I want to be able to load assembly at run time and being able to use all of it's types in my code.

I know how to instantiate an object by loading an assembly:
 that is  by

```
assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\PowerTool.exe");

            Type type = assembly.GetType("PowerTool.Automation");
            powerTool = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

But that will allow me to access one object of the entire assembly. But if I want to use other members of the assembly like enums and other static classes then how can I do it?

If I was referencing to the assembly at the compile time then I should be able to do somehting like Assemblyname.membername. But since I am loading this one at runtime. How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you do `assembly.GetType()` to get the other types, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *all* types (including private types) use [`Assembly.GetTypes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx)

```
assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\PowerTool.exe");

foreach(Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
```

If you want only *public* types use [`GetExportedTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexportedtypes.aspx):

```
foreach(Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
    Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
```